# Find values to the left and right of the last period with regex and separate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, regex-lookarounds

I have a dataframe with column names like the following:

```
[127] "quiz.32.player.submitted_answer_private"         "quiz.32.player.rescue_event"                    
[129] "quiz.33.player.solution"                         "quiz.33.player.submitted_answer"                
[131] "quiz.33.player.submitted_answer_private"         "quiz.33.player.rescue_event"                    
[133] "partner_quiz.1.player.solution"                  "partner_quiz.1.player.submitted_answer"         
[135] "partner_quiz.1.player.submitted_answer_private"  "partner_quiz.1.player.rescue_event"             
[137] "partner_quiz.2.player.solution"                  "partner_quiz.2.player.submitted_answer"         
[139] "partner_quiz.2.player.submitted_answer_private"  "partner_quiz.2.player.rescue_event"
```

I am trying to separate these values by extracting the value to the right of the last period and the value to the left of it. My dplyr pipeline for for this is as follows:

```
frame <- data %>%
  gather(k, value) %>%
  separate(k, into = c("quiz_number", "suffix"), sep = "\\.(?=player)")
```

For some reason the resulting data.frame omits all columns that are prefixed with "partner."  Any ideas why?

Edit: The resulting split should have in the column `quiz_number` all the content to the left of the last period (e.g.
`quiz.32.player` and `partner_quiz.2.player`)  and in the "suffix" column, all the content to the right of the last period (e.g. `submitted_answer_private` and `solution`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the 'player' in regex lookaround, do a positive match for characters that are not a `.` till the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   gather(k, value) %>%
   separate(k, into = c("quiz_number", "suffix"), sep = "\\.(?=[^.]+$)")
```

---

In the OP's code, it is matching `.` before the 'player' string, but there are `.`s after the 'player' e.g. `quiz.32.player.rescue_event`

Comment: You answered this question in 42 seconds.  You deserve an award.  Any ideas what was wrong with my regex?